# Kotlin Navigation - Back Button not working

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have the following code in Kotlin

```
package com.example.android.navigation
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
    import androidx.navigation.findNavController
    import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
    import com.example.android.navigation.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val navcon = this.findNavController(R.id.NavFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navcon)

    }

    override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navcon = this.findNavController(R.id.NavFragment)
        return navcon.navigateUp()
    }

}
```

The code is supposed to implement the back button and make it work correctly (navigate up the back stack). However, when I run the application and click on the generated back button, nothing happens (the button doesn't work, but also no error is produced when clicked). Does anyone have any idea as to why it doesn't work / how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` has a separate [`onSupportNavigateUp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity?hl=en#onSupportNavigateUp()) method, which should be used instead of `onNavigateUp()` as per the [Navigation Action Bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar).